# Exclude apostrophes from SQL Server Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I would like to know how to exclude apostrophes from being indexed in full text search.

For example, if someone enters a search term for "o'brien" or for "obrien" I would want it to match all cases where someone's name matches either "O'Brien" or "OBrien".

However, if I search on:

```
select * from MyTable where contains (fullName, '"o''Brien*"')
```

It returns only ones with an apostrophe.
But if I do:

```
select * from MyTable where contains (fullName, '"oBrien*"')
```

It only returns the ones without an apostrophe.

In short, I want to know if it is possible for FTS to index both "O'Brien" and "OBrien" as "obrien" so that I can find both.

While the solution:

```
select * from MyTable where contains (fullName, '"oBrien*" OR "o''Brien*"')
```

would work, however, I can't make that assumption if the user entered "obrien".

I'm looking for a solution that works both on SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: Version of SQL Server? (FTS changed quite a lot between 2005 and 2008)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676019/apostrophes-and-sql-server-ft-search

Comment: The possible dupe is SQL 2005 specific.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the possible dupe is 2005 specific'?

Comment: @Avrom - I was responding to Jacob's "possible duplicate" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on how much space you have, you could add another column

> fullName_noPunctuation

containing only the alpha characters of the name, strip punctuation from your search criteria, and search the punctuation-free column instead.

Comment: This may work for me. I'll have to look into it. However, it would be nicer if there was a way to get it to just index "O'Brien" and "OBrien" as "obrien".

Comment: Added a new column with the "fullName" stripped of its apostrophes and created a FTS index on it. It was able to find both the O'Briens and the Obriens using a contains (fullSearch, '"obrien*"').